# REST - filter dates in between

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, datatable

If the current request is for 04/02/2018 - 04/06/2018, I need to display in a datatable any other requests that include 04/02 - 04/06. For example, the datatable should display the following requests

- ID 1 - Employee A - 04/02/2018
- ID 2 - Employee B - 04/04/2018-04/05/2018
- ID 3 - Employee C - 04/04/2018-04/09/2018

Below code displays ID#1 and 2 in the datatable but not 3 and I can't figure out how to include ID#3.

```
var dateArray = dateString.split(",");
var stDate = new Date(dateArray[0]);
var enDate = new Date(dateArray[1]);

var checkInfo = webAbsUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('AbsenceRequest')/Items?$\
    filter=((StartDateISO ge datetime'" + stDate.toISOString() + "') and (EndDateISO le datetime'" + enDate.toISOString() + "') and (Section eq '" + strA + "'))&$\
    top=300&$select=Id, Absentee, RequestType, ActivityType, EventDate, EndDate, Status";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three types of matches:

- StartDateISO between the two dates
- EndDateISO between the two dates
- StartDateISO < stDate AND EndDateISO > enDate

So try this:

```
(
  (StartDateISO ge datetime'" + stDate.toISOString() + "') and (StartDateISO le datetime'" + enDate.toISOString() + "')
or
  (EndDateISO ge datetime'" + stDate.toISOString() + "') and (EndtDateISO le datetime'" + enDate.toISOString() + "')
or
  (StartDateISO le datetime'" + stDate.toISOString() + "') and (EndDateISO ge datetime'" + enDate.toISOString() + "')
)
```

Note that this does not deal with either date being blank.